# JPA/Hibernate Insert Object with Child Object and Child Objects depending on first Child

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to insert an Object (Parent) into my Database where the parent object has a list of child objects (Child1) and a second list of children (Child2) which contain references to the first Child. I want to insert them in one Request (I'm using Spring boot with REST) with a request like this:

```
{
    "name": "Parent 1",
    "children1": [
        {
            "id": 0,
            "name": "Test 0",
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Test 1",
        }
    ],
    "children2": [
        [
            {
                "label": "Label 0",
                "children1": 0
            },
            null,
            {
                "label": "Label 1",
                "children1": 1
            }
        ]
}
```

I'm using `@JsonIdentityInfo()` to map the children1 objects "into" the Children2 objects which works fine. But when I try to save the Parent (`parentRepository.save(parent)`) i get `org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException` because the ID's of the child1 objects are autogenerated so when it tries to insert the child2 objects with the "old" ID's used  in the JSON they are not "linked" anymore. How can I fix this?

The parent Object looks like this:

```
    // Parent.class

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    private List<Child1> children1;

    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    private List<Child2> children2;
```

The first Child Object looks like this:

```
    //Child1.class

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 200)
    private String name;
```

And finally the second child class looks like this:

```
    //Child2.class

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 10)
    private String label;

    @ManyToOne
    private Child1 child1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `CascadeType.PERSIST` , Parent entity :

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE }, orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
private Set<Child> children;
```

And Child entity :

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Parent parent;
```

It'll insert children after parent is inserted with just one *jpa* query ->

```
repository.save(parent);
```